# Is a time loop possible?

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light, time-travel, wormholes, closed-timelike-curve

Let's say that hypothetically we could travel faster than light. Would a ship travelling at lightspeed or faster than light travel create a time loop where it makes the same trip over and over again over the same period of time?

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/342444/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_timelike_curve